# Setting up Multiple TFS 2012 projects that use a common core library?

Tags: tfs

I have a core library we use in multiple projects. There are times we add to the core library, but regardless of the project we do not branch the core. We feel that anything that is in the core can be used for another project down the road or added to an existing project. If something is very unique to a project it would inherit from the core and be its own assembly.

With that said, is there a better way to have our core project span multiple TFS projects? In the past we have either just referenced the assemblies or have used nuget. Since we update the core regularly, we would like to reference the core library project directly.

I am only asking this question in case 2012 offers a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to source control, TFS 2012 does introduce new features such as [local workspaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx) and native [Git integration](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30474), but the core concepts remain the same. Personally I think NuGet is currently the best practice for such scenarios.